# Android file picker and standard mime types

Tags: android, mime-types, android-intent, android-contentprovider

I want to start another activity so the user can pick a file to use in my app.  (Specifically an audio file in this case.)  I googled and found this:

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/03/pick-file-using-intentactiongetcontent.html.

Basically it creates an `Intent` with `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and mime type "file/*".  Questions:

- Where is it documented, in the standard Android docs, that this will start a file chooser?
- Can I depend on it?  That is, is it part of Android or does it only work if the user has a certain file manager app installed.
- Is this the best way to choose a file?  I specifically want an audio file (mp3, etc) - one of the audio files on the SD card that the standard music player knows about, somehow.  Should I look at ContentProviders?

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't mention the "file/*" mime type, which I've never seen.  Is that documented somewhere too?